# Is there an authoritative data source for EM spectrum assignments?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, spectroscopy, data

I'm working on [some software](https://github.com/yunruse/noether) to coalesce various standard constants (eg SI, CODATA, AME) into an easy-access library. However, trying to find an authoritative source I can find for EM spectrum assignments is a little less clear, which I suppose makes sense for its use. The [ITU](https://www.itu.int/en/publications/ITU-R/pages/publications.aspx?parent=R-SP-LN.IS-2020&media=electronic)'s source is costly, the [FCC](https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/spectrum/table/fcctable.pdf)'s overly specific, and so on. Is there a common authoritative source for the EM spectrum, or is it as subjective as it seems?

Comment: 'Spectrum assignments' in what sense? The FCC is, not surprisingly, quite specific with what uses are allowed in what frequencies since that is exactly what they are supposed to do. But, that is licensing, not physics. What physics principles are you after?

Comment: @JonCuster Major and minor delineations, mostly. Visible light is pretty obvious, but it doesn't seem particularly obvious what *exactly* constitutes a gamma ray, especially in academic writings where you might be towards the edge of the definition.

Comment: Well, different parts of physics have different definitions of gamma rays. In astronomy it seems a gamma is anything above 10MeV, while I'm more used to gammas coming from nuclear processes and x-rays from electronic processes so they can both have similar energies. Similarly, different communities have different definitions of near-, mid-, and far-infrared. And, lets not discuss the radio spectrum... So, no, there is not an authoritative source, since different fields have historically split it up differently for different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ISO 21348](http://www.spacewx.com/pdf/SET_21348_2004.pdf) seems to be a good set of definitions, with major and minor categorisation (eg Radio and UHF).

Comment: I'll leave it for a bit just in case somebody has a better answer than I, but ISO seems inherently as authoritative as you can get.